# Spaces in getopt() argument causes parsing to fail

Tags: c

I'm using `optarg`. The argument I'm entering is split to spaces even if I'm quoting it.

My code:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "d:f:")) != -1)
    switch (c) {
        case 'd':
            dflag++;
            break;
        case 'f':
            fflag++;
            break;
        case '?':
            if (optopt == 'd' || optopt == 'f')
                fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
            else if (isprint(optopt))
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
            else
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                        optopt);
            return 1;
        default:
            usage();
            return 1;
    }

if (fflag > 1 || dflag > 1 || fflag >= 1 && dflag >= 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please choose one option only.");
    return 1;
}

for (index = optind; index < argc; index++) {
    printf("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
    usage();
}

printf("%s",optarg);
```

I run it like this:

```
a.exe -d "c:\Program Files\"
```

The output is:

```
C:\Program
```

This is the getopt code I'm using: 
https://github.com/seastorm/PuttyRider/blob/master/Wingetopt.c

Comment: Maybe it is not the problem, but I don't think your use of `optarg` if correct. This pointer is modified every time you call `getopt()` so when it returns `-1`, `optarg` will be undefined. You should use a local variable to keep its value.

Comment: be aware that because of `"d:"` the path name is interpreted as argument of '-d', but in `case 'd'` you do nothing with `optarg`

Comment: The first thing I'd do is add code to print the values of `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc. That would either eliminate or confirm the possibility that the problem is in `getopt` or in your use of it. `getopt` can only work with the contents of the `argv` array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your arguments, not with your code. The last two characters on your command line (`\"`) lead to the effect that the last double quote gets escaped. Therefore your quoting fails.

For me your code works if I add a trailing white space character behind the backslash:

```
a.exe -d "c:\Program Files\ "
```

It also works if I escape the backslash in front of the double quote:

```
a.exe -d "c:\Program Files\\"
```

I compiled the code on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2012. I added the following lines at the beginning of your code so that it compiles:

```
int c = 0;
int dflag = 0;
int fflag = 0;
int index = 0;
```